# how do i write a code in python that compares two strings A and B

Tags: python

How can I compare two strings `A` and `B`, such that it will print `'true'` if ALL the letters in `A` are in `B` but print `'false'` if not. Note the two strings may not be of equal lengths. I tried using a `for` loop but it only tests the first letter of `A`

```
A=''
B=''
for c in A:
        if c not in B:
            print('False')
        else:
            print('True')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your string to [set()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):

```
A = "fedca"
B = "abcdefg"

if set(A) <= set(B):
  print("All the letters of A are contained in B")
```